# Avatar as JPEG in Discord Oauth2 PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, discord

I am making a website that uses discord OAuth2 login. I want to get the Avatar from the Oauth2 and I want it in terms of JPEG. Is there any way to get the image in JPEG(even if the user has a gif as the avatar) in php.

here is my code to request information from oauth2

```
$params = array(
    'client_id' => OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:80/dwayne',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => 'identify guilds email',
    'size' => 16
  );
  header('Location: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize' . '?' . http_build_query($params));
  die();
```

This is given in the documentation

Discord uses ids and hashes to render images in the client. These hashes can be retrieved through various API requests, like Get User. Below are the formats, size limitations, and CDN endpoints for images in Discord. The returned format can be changed by changing the extension name at the end of the URL. The returned size can be changed by appending a querystring of ?size=desired_size to the URL. Image size can be any power of two between 16 and 4096.

I did not understand the given text from the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avatar formats can be changed by changing the ending extension of the code like

`<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/'. $user->id. '/'. $user->avatar .'.png" alt="'. $user->username.'" />`

in this `$user` is the result of the request sent to Oauth. and if you want to change the format into `.jpeg` then the code would be

`<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/'. $user->id. '/'. $user->avatar .'.jpg" alt="'. $user->username.'" />`